# Scenekit - SCNLookupConstraint causes ConvertPosition of childNode not to update its position

Tags: scenekit, swift4

I have a main node, with a sequence of childNodes.  The childNodes are firePoints, so as the target comes into view, the main node rotates to target and the firepoint is an offset where I need to shoot from.  It works fine if I target via some vector classes I built, but it is smoother if I use SCNConstraint on the main node.  The main node (and firepoints) rotate to target, but the fire points vector values do not ever change when convertPosition is called.  I can see that the fireNodes are rotating along with the base node properly.  Thanks

```
func shoot()
    {
        isShooting = true
        // Convert position so that projectile fires from FirePoint
        let fireNode        = gNodes.getNode(vName: attr.name + "FirePoint" + "\(attr.firePointsSequence)", vRequired: true, vError: "FP0-Sproj")
        let fireNodeStart   = gNodes.gameNodes.convertPosition(fireNode.presentation.position, from: attr.node)

        print("FireNodePosition: \(fireNodeStart) 
}
func setTarget()
    {
        attr.node.constraints = []
        let vConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: targetNode)
        vConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
        attr.node.constraints = [vConstraint]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem. What solved it for me was using SCN's presentation scn. It has  up to date positions.

Comment: Allen - that makes perfect sense  - I never thought of trying it.  Pretty handy piece of info if you need this functionality - thanks